# Define ActiveMQ service from the CLI

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

In ActiveMQ you can define a service in the XML config:

```
<services>  
   <masterConnector remoteURI="tcp://localhost:61616" userName="User1" password="pass1"/>  
 </services>
```

Is it possible to define this via the command line and pass it at the starting time when we run `activemq start` cmd? I've already digged in the configuration and I didn't find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the broker needs to be configured using the XML file or in Java code using the embedded broker option.